# How to add a driver to body text

Tags: python, drivers

I would like to have an empty with custom string property that drive a Body Text. But Body Text datablock is not accessible from the GUI. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

After adding a text object, finding out the name of the associated property ("body") and selecting it...

```
>>> C.scene.objects.active.data.driver_add("body")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "body" not animatable
```

That is, I tried to add a driver to it from the python console. It doesn't seem to be possible, sorry. Depending on what exactly you want to put in the text object, using multiple objects might be an option?